# PL/sql stored procedure ref cursor as parameter

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to pass multiple rows to a stored procedure. Can I use a ref cursor? because I have tried the following:

Inside my package I have:

```
TYPE FACT_VND_RECORD
IS
  RECORD
  (
    COD_NOMCPDT P6PCM2_PARMCMS.COD_NOMCPDT%TYPE,
    LIB_LIBNOMCPDT P6PCM2_PARMCMS.LIB_LIBNOMCPDT%TYPE,
    DHS_MAJ P6PCM2_PARMCMS.DHS_MAJ%TYPE,
    LIB_AUTH_MAJ P6PCM2_PARMCMS.LIB_AUTH_MAJ%TYPE );

TYPE FACT_VND_CURSOR
    IS
      REF
      CURSOR
        RETURN FACT_VND_RECORD;
```

and 2 procedures:

```
PROCEDURE REC_FACT_VND(
      P_IN_NUM_VND   IN OUT P6PCM2_PARMCMS.NUM_VND%TYPE,
      P_OUT_FACT_VND IN OUT FACT_VND_CURSOR,
      P_OUT_CODE_RET OUT INTEGER,
      P_OUT_MSG_ERR OUT VARCHAR2);

  PROCEDURE MAJ_FACT_VND(
      P_IN_NUM_VND   IN OUT P6PCM2_PARMCMS.NUM_VND%TYPE,
      P_IN_FACT_VND IN OUT FACT_VND_CURSOR,
      P_OUT_CODE_RET OUT INTEGER,
      P_OUT_MSG_ERR OUT VARCHAR2);
```

Recieves the previously filled cursor and does something with the data.

I use these 2 calls; The first one works OK, I can see the data inside ref cursor C1 and then I try to use it.

```
C1 PACK_REC_FACT_VND.FACT_VND_CURSOR;
--other definitons
      PACK_REC_FACT_VND.REC_FACT_VND(NUM_VND,C1,COD_RET,MSG_ERR);
    PACK_REC_FACT_VND.MAJ_FACT_VND(NUM_VND,C1,COD_RET,MSG_ERR);
```

I can't iterate over the data  because it is undefined: 
(Code from second procedure)

```
LIGNE_TAUX PACK_REC_FACT_VND.FACT_VND_RECORD;
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM P6PCM2_PARMCMS WHERE NUM_VND=P_IN_NUM_VND;
      FOR LIGNE_TAUX IN P_IN_FACT_VND
      LOOP
        INSERT
        INTO P6PCM2_PARMCMS VALUES
          (
            P_IN_NUM_VND,   
LIGNE_TAUX.COD_NOMCPDT, 
LIGNE_TAUX.LIB_LIBNOMCPDT, 
LIGNE_TAUX.DHS_MAJ, 
LIGNE_TAUX.LIB_AUTH_MAJ);
      END LOOP;

Error(48,21): PLS-00221: 'P_IN_FACT_VND' is not a procedure or is undefined
```

Or should I switch to TABLE OF RECORD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't use ref cursors like that; we need to use the explicit cursor syntax.  Try this (warning: untested code!):

```
        LIGNE_TAUX PACK_REC_FACT_VND.FACT_VND_RECORD;
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM P6PCM2_PARMCMS WHERE NUM_VND=P_IN_NUM_VND;

      LOOP
         fetch P_IN_FACT_VND   into LIGNE_TAUX; 
         exit when P_IN_FACT_VND%notfound;
        INSERT
        INTO P6PCM2_PARMCMS VALUES
          (
            P_IN_NUM_VND,   
            LIGNE_TAUX.COD_NOMCPDT, 
            LIGNE_TAUX.LIB_LIBNOMCPDT, 
            LIGNE_TAUX.DHS_MAJ, 
            LIGNE_TAUX.LIB_AUTH_MAJ);
      END LOOP;

  close P_IN_FACT_VND;
```

However, get better performance if you fetch the records into a collection.  Something like this:

```
        type LIGNE_TAUX_NT is table of PACK_REC_FACT_VND.FACT_VND_RECORD;
        LIGNE_TAUX_COLL LIGNE_TAUX_NT;
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM P6PCM2_PARMCMS WHERE NUM_VND=P_IN_NUM_VND;

      fetch P_IN_FACT_VND bulk collect  into LIGNE_TAUX_COLL; 
      close P_IN_FACT_VND;

      -- while we're at it why not use the more efficient FORALL syntax 
      -- to perform the inserts?


      forall idx in LIGNE_TAUX_COLL.first() .. LIGNE_TAUX_COLL.last()
            INSERT
           INTO P6PCM2_PARMCMS VALUES
              (
            P_IN_NUM_VND,   
            LIGNE_TAUX_COLL(idx).COD_NOMCPDT, 
            LIGNE_TAUX_COLL(idx).LIB_LIBNOMCPDT, 
            LIGNE_TAUX_COLL(idx).DHS_MAJ, 
            LIGNE_TAUX_COLL(idx).LIB_AUTH_MAJ);
```

[Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#i7106).

Comment: the table of record was my second thought..i'll give it a try! and come with an answer.

Comment: I switched to table of records as input parameter because I find it safer to use :) 10x anyway